# What (if any) is the distinction between "verisimilitudinous" and "verisimilar"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives

I was translating some Spanish and found myself wanting a word for "possessing verisimilitude". My first thought was "verisimilitudinous", but some research revealed that "verisimilar" is also a word. The dictionaries I've checked don't seem clear on any distinction between the two (or between "verisimilitude" and "verisimilarity").

Wiktionary defines "verisimilitudinous" as "appearing to be verisimilar; exhibiting verisimilitude, in either a neutral or a dubious sense" and "verisimilar" as "Appearing to be true or real; probable; likely" (i.e. exhibiting verisimilitude). Merriam-Webster online defines "verisimilar" as "having the appearance of truth" and redirects "verisimilitudinous" to "verisimilitude", which is defined using "verisimilar".

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: Thanks and which dictionaries did you check, and what did they suggest, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin See my edit

Comment: Thanks and still, can you not explain why you don't or do see a differrence?

Otherwise, you're basically asking ELU to act as your dictionary…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Merriam-Webster implies that they have the same meaning as it defines verisimilitude in terms of verisimilarity, whereas the "appearing to be verisimilar" and "in... a dubious sense" parts of Wiktionary's definition of verisimilitudinous suggest a difference. I am perfectly capable of reading dictionary definitions; I was hoping that someone here would know something relevant about different/same usage of the words.

Comment: Please take this seriously, or drop it.

What Merriam-Webster actually said is what I was asking. What you infer Merriam-Webster might have meant is worth what?

There could be such a word as "verisimilitudinous", and would that not be more an exercise in mechanical possibility than any kind of linguistic reality?

For instance, since we recognise “antidisestablishmentarianism” we ought, mechanically, to recognise “antidisestablishmentarianistic” but do we? Google it!

I suggest "verisimilitudinous" has roughly the same value in language as “antidisestablishmentarianistic”.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If by "has roughly the same value in language" you mean "isn't used", maybe you should Google it! It's used twice on [this](https://literaryterms.net/verisimilitude/) page.

Comment: N.B. regardless of how frequently "verisimilitudinous" is used (which I agree is a relevant consideration), it's not comparable to "antidisestablishmentarianistic". Creating an adjective from a property by adding "-inous" or similar is common and semantically meaningful, whereas adding "-sitic" to nouns for people (such as "antidisestablismentarian") isn't -- you wouldn't say "vegetarianistic". I think a better example would've been "antidisestablishmentarianish", which is meaningful.

Comment: P.S. Someone on reddit claims [there](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/70t42e/eli5_is_there_a_distinction_between_the_words/) is a difference.

Comment: Having established the same theoretical background that I pointed out, can you please prove some instances of anyone ever using it?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Please reread my 14:45 comment, which links to an example of use. Please also reread the next one, which is *not* establishing the same theoretical background you pointed out but rather disagreeing with you.

Comment: Sorry, rlms, please just recognise that although "verisimilitudinous" is clearly a theoretically possible word, and might very well have been used a few times, that doesn't make it anything like as likely as "verisimilar” which in itself is rather dubious.

I'm sorry you don't follow the processes and there is no good reason why one wouldn't say "vegetarianistic" in the right circumstances.

Why would it be difficult to start from the Spanish equivalents of “veresi(anything)” and formally translate each, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Please provide some evidence for your claims about the relative frequency of use of different words. Also please explain what you mean by "follow the processes".

Comment: Uh… of course not. I made no claim about relative frequency. 

When I said "you don't follow the processes" I meant that you didn't seem to grasp the idea that some words appear in stylised groups as, for example but by no means limited to "vegetarian" then "vegetarianist" then "vegetarianistic". You might also include at least "vegetarianised" and possibly "vegetarianal"… the details that stem from "vegetarian" don't matter; the process does.

Do you follow that process?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin You claimed that "verisimilar" was relatively more frequent than "verisimilitudinous" didn't you? (In your comment on June 27). N.B. my spellchecker recognises the latter but not the former.

Comment: Certainly I understand that words can be derived from each other by morphological derivation. But you don't seem to graph the idea (tangential to the main question) that not all morphological derivations by addition of suffixes give equivalently meaningful words.

Comment: Jolly good. Why not go back ask yourself 'What (if any) is the distinction between “verisimilitudinous” and “verisimilar”, please? Does anyone else seem to think that's a useful Question or what, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Asking myself what the distinction between the two words is would obviously be pointless -- the reason I'm asking here is because I don't know!

Comment: I'm not sure what other people think about the utility of this Question, but according to the sidebar the distinctions between "supernatural" and "paranormal", "pillage" and "plunder", "ambulate" and "perambulate", "nonessential" and "inessential", "pagan" and "heathen",  and "pottage" and "potage" were considered interesting, so I don't see why this wouldn't be. Maybe you don't find it interesting, but no-one's forcing you to consider it.

Comment: Oh, gosh. Could you just go back and first find at least two or three other sources on top of MW, then explain what among them they leave unclear?

Comment: I don't really see why I should, to be quite honest.

Answer (score 1):

On the distinction between between verisimilitude and verisimilarity.  [Univ.Houston](http://coursesite.uhcl.edu/HSH/Whitec/terms/V/verisimilitude.htm)

Oxford English Dictionary: [from Latin: "like truth"]

> **verisimilar** **verisimilarity**: Having the appearance or semblance of truth or reality; appearing true or real; possible.

ie possible!

Whereas:

> **verisimilitude**: The fact or quality of being verisimilar; the appearance of being true or real; likeness or resemblance to truth,
>   reality, or fact; probability.

ie probable!

I was taught to use 'very similar', avoiding the use of verisimilar so as to not sound like i knew a comparison to be fact based. In fact one reference says of verisimilar-arity:  it's [not a english word](https://wikidiff.com/verisimilarity/verisimilitude). 'Verisimilitude' lends more ... similitude! More fact and/orreality based than the casual very similar.

As in:

> The comparison of the two seemed to be very similar ... The comparison
>   of the two revealed  a distinct verisimilitude.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend by these two definitions. Canyou explicitly compare them? How are they different and how the same? What do you mean by 'very similar' which sounds awfully like 'verisimilar'; you're not saying _why_ you avoid 'verisimilar'.  This all would help understand by 'with the above in mind' because currently there is no claim made to have in mind.

Comment: @Mitch i edited in an attempt to be more clear. indeed verisimilar to my sense can be mis-heard or read as verisimilitude. If my answer is salvageable i would ask you edit, suggest edits or rec deletion.